# extjs grid sort case insensitvie

Tags: extjs

In extjs grid we can see column can be sort Ascending or Sort Descending. But in this case they sort as case sensitive. How can I change this to case insensitive?
Ex. Now ti works as
111, 123, Apple, Untitled ,Untitled 01, apple, qqq

How can I change this to

111, 123, Apple, apple, Untitled, Untitled 01,aqq

Answer (score 2):

This is covered in the docs:

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.SortTypes
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Field